# ¿Como responder a las preguntas SI o NO en vez de tener que responder con boolean (TRUE o FALSE) JAVA

Tags: java

El problema es, escribe un programa que pida por teclado al usuario el nombre de un alumno (String), su edad (entero) y también le debe preguntar si aprobó la ESO (booleano), si repitió algún curso (booleano) y en caso afirmativo cuántos cursos repitió (entero).

Sabiendo que los alumnos terminan la ESO con 16 años, los datos que ha introducido y el año actual (Calendar), puede deducir aproximadamente en qué curso acabó la ESO. Debe mostrar un mensaje indicando estos datos.
Ejemplo: "En Lluis tiene 20 años, tiene aprobada la ESO, repitió 2 veces y terminó en el año 2019"

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    
    public class test2 {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            String nom = " ";
            int edat = 0;
            boolean aprovar;
            boolean repetir = false;
            int quantsrepetit = 0;
    
            Scanner teclat = new Scanner(System.in);
            Calendar any = Calendar.getInstance();
            int anyactual = (any.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    
            System.out.print("Introdueix el teu nom: "); //Introduce tu nombre.
            nom = teclat.nextLine();
    
            System.out.print("Introdueix la teva edat: "); //Introduce tu edad.
            edat = teclat.nextInt();
    
            System.out.print("Has aprovat la ESO? "); //Has aprobado la ESO?
            aprovar = teclat.nextBoolean();
    
            if (aprovar){
                System.out.print("Has repetit algun curs? "); //Has repetido algun curso?
                repetir = teclat.nextBoolean();
            }
    
            if (repetir){
                System.out.print("Quants cursos has repetit? "); //Cuantos cursos has repetido
                quantsrepetit = teclat.nextInt();
            }
            int x = edat - 16;
            int y = (anyactual - x); 
    
            int acaba = (y + quantsrepetit);
    
            System.out.print("En "+nom+" te "+edat+" anys, té "+aprovar+" la ESO, va repetir "+quantsrepetit+" vegades i va acabar l’any "+acaba+".");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa variables tipo `String` y compara usando `.equalsIgnoreCase("si")`, para que al escribir "si" no importando si escribes en mayusculas o minusculas la cadena determine afirmativamente, ejemplo:

```
System.out.print("Has aprovat la ESO? ");
aprovar = teclat.next();

if (aprovar.equalsIgnoreCase("si")){
    System.out.print("Has repetit algun curs? "); 
    repetir = teclat.next();
}else{ 
   //Respuesta no es afirmativa.
}
```

esto serìa el còdigo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    String nom = " ";
    int edat = 0;
    //boolean aprovar;
    String aprovar;
    //boolean repetir = false;
    String repetir = "";
    int quantsrepetit = 0;

    Scanner teclat = new Scanner(System.in);
    Calendar any = Calendar.getInstance();
    int anyactual = (any.get(Calendar.YEAR));

    System.out.print("Introdueix el teu nom: "); //Introduce tu nombre.
    nom = teclat.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Introdueix la teva edat: "); //Introduce tu edad.
    edat = teclat.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Has aprovat la ESO? "); //Has aprobado la ESO?
    aprovar = teclat.next();//teclat.nextBoolean();

    if (aprovar.equalsIgnoreCase("si")){
        System.out.print("Has repetit algun curs? "); //Has repetido algun curso?
        repetir = teclat.next();//teclat.nextBoolean();
    }

    if (repetir.equalsIgnoreCase("si")){
        System.out.print("Quants cursos has repetit? "); //Cuantos cursos has repetido
        quantsrepetit = teclat.nextInt();
    }
    int x = edat - 16;
    int y = (anyactual - x); 

    int acaba = (y + quantsrepetit);

    System.out.print("En "+nom+" te "+edat+" anys, té "+aprovar+" la ESO, va repetir "+quantsrepetit+" vegades i va acabar l’any "+acaba+".");
}
```